# Wrong replacement of strings with gsub in R

Tags: r, syntax, gsub

I am trying to exclude all `".1"` occurences from my `labelexp` data frame.

My input

```
     ID
1 NE001403
2 NE001458.1
3 NE001494.1
4 NE001634.1
5 NE001635.1
6 NE001637.1
```

I have tried it: `labelexp$ID <- gsub(".1", "", labelexp$ID)`, but my output was:

```
    ID
1 NE0403
2 NE0458
3 NE0494
4 NE0634
5 NE0635
6 NE0637
```

Any ideas? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "`.`" is a special character in regular expressions in R - it means any character. You need to put "`\\`" in front of it to tell R that you mean it to be the character ".". Thus, try:

```
labelexp$ID <- gsub("\\.1", "", labelexp$ID)
```

Does that work for you?

Answer (score 3):

You can also use `fixed=TRUE` option:

```
 sub(".1", "","NE001458.1",fixed=TRUE)
 "NE001458"
```